# Can I create a SUMIF with data from either of 2 columns?

Tags: excel, google-sheets

I am creating a budgeting table. I am using SUMIF (Category, "Category Name", Amount). However, I have 2 sets of "Amount" - Budgeted and Actual.

How do I make it in such a way that the SUMIF for that Category would add the data from Budgeted if the Actual field is blank?

Comment: Some sample data and the expected output would be helpful here.

Comment: Could you share a sanitized copy of your spreadsheet, containing the desired output?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

check the ";" maybe you have to replace it with a ","

```
=SUMIFS(Amount;Category;SelectedCategory)+SUMIFS(Budget;Category;SelectedCategory;Amount;"")
```

Comment: Better explicitly check that Amount is not blank in the first part: `=SUMIFS(Amount, Amount; "<>", Category, SelectedCategory) + SUMIFS(Budget, Amount, "", Category, SelectedCategory)`

Comment: Thanks @kishkin But I think it isn‘t a problem if an empty Amount will be added :). But also it isn‘t a problem to avoid this..

Answer (score 0):

Another way to do this is to have a column that represents the value to sum.

New column:
=if(isblank(Amount), Budget, Amount)

Then you just sumifs the new column by category.